# Php function return database connection doesn't work when included in other files

Tags: php, database, mysqli, include, connection

What I want is to make a file with the database connection and get it return by a function so I can call it in other files were needed but I keep getting undefined function or undefined variable .. this is my code

```
function db()
{
    $host = "text";
    $user = "text";
    $password = "text";
    $database = "text";
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if(!$db)
    {
        die('OOOPS'.mysql_errno());    
    }
    else{
        return $db;    
    }
}
```

all I do in the other files is
    require it and then using then $db 
    to run querys 
I am using the latest version of xaamp with php 5.6

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: for example if u want to run a query i call it on top of the file and then use $db  variable lets say mysqli_query($db,$query)

Comment: Can you post full code for me to check syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the errors first. You're mixing libraries, `mysql_` and `mysqli_` **can not and will not work with eachother**. You need to pick one and go with it. Now you should pick the `mysqli_*` option because `mysql_` is deprecated:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

<sup>[*Taken from the php.net manual*](http://php.net/mysql_connect)</sup>

---

Now what you're doing, is extremely bad. You're opening so many connections. Take it out of a function and have it like this:

```
$host = "text";
$user = "text";
$password = "text";
$database = "text";
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
if(!$db) {
    die('OOOPS'.mysqli_error());    
}
```

Now you just need to include the above file (called whatever you want, like `db.php` or something) on every page you intend to use the database.

This eliminates you having to do this every single time you want to use the database:

```
$db = db();
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Which is rather redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This error because you not run the db() function, so the $db var is undefined yet.
If you will using this file as a connection file you don't need a function.